# Regex in Tableau pattern

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following string.

> p3266 -- MR2015 - Conversion Task 5 - TRF for PLM 2016-08-13.fixTrfWorkOrder -- TRF Header Work Order to WBS conversion 2016-08-25. LCI# PYF

Im trying to regex just the (LCI# PYF) 
this is what i have so far.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([\n\r].[*LCI\s*]([^\n\r]*)
```

how every this string is not always the same. sometimes there is the space between the # XXX sometimes not. I mainly need just the 3 digit letters (PYF) to be the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT('p3266 -- MR2015 - Conversion Task 5 - TRF for PLM 2016-08-13.fixTrfWorkOrder -- TRF Header Work Order to WBS conversion 2016-08-25. LCI# PYF',
               'LCI#\s*(\S+)')
```

This would match and capture the non whitespace term appearing after `LCI#`, which is followed by optional whitespace.

### Demo

Comment: what if my expression is not always what is above. could be as follows ("
p3266 -- MR2015 - Conversion Task 5 - TRF for PLM 2016-08-13.fixTrfWorkOrder -- TRF Header Work Order to WBS conversion 2016-08-25.

LCI# MSQ"
) 
some of my strings just have the LCI#ABD also i would just want to extract the (ABD)

Comment: getting "unexpected text" in Tableau Prep builder

Comment: REGEXP_EXTRACT([PLANNER_NOTE],LCI#\s*(\S+))

Comment: Pretty sure you would need quotes around the regex pattern.

Comment: Is it possible to combine these together in one Regex formula to account for spaces   (LCI\s#\s*(\S+) & (LCI#\s*(\S+) there seems to be 3 versions either LCI # ABC or LCI#ABC or LCI# ABC

Comment: @kevinP Just use: `LCI\s*#\s*(\S+)`